# JMS and ThreadPool problem?

Tags: java, spring, jms, threadpool

I want that jms receives a message when one thread has handled a message (threadPool submits a callable).
The messages are received by a master thread.
Which way is better below:

I use spring 3.0.5  :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "application-context.xml");
jmsTemplate = (JmsTemplate) context.getBean("jmsTemplate");
destination = (Destination) context.getBean("destination");
_log4j.debug("ThreadSize in xml\t"
        + appConfig.getThumbCreatorThreadSize());
```

in master thread Way 1:

```
while (countFlag < 0) {
    try {
        TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) jmsTemplate
                .receive(destination);
        // prehandle ,then give to sub workers.
        if (msg != null) {
            _log4j.debug("JMSMessageID:\t" + msg.getJMSMessageID()
                    + "\t" + msg.getText());
            IConsumer thumbConsumerImpl = null;
            thumbConsumerImpl = new ThumbConsumerTaskImpl(msg);
            Future<List<ThumbCreatorInfo>> result = threadPool
                    .submit((Callable<List<ThumbCreatorInfo>>) thumbConsumerImpl);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        _log4j.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        _log4j.error("Please check the queue server!JMSException!", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log4j.error("", e);
    }
}
```

in master thread Way 2:

```
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(destination);
    do {
        try {
            // prehandle ,then give to sub workers.
            if (msg != null) {
                _log4j.debug("JMSMessageID:\t" + msg.getJMSMessageID()
                        + "\t" + msg.getText());
                IConsumer thumbConsumerImpl = null;
                thumbConsumerImpl = new ThumbConsumerTaskImpl(msg);
                Future<List<ThumbCreatorInfo>> result = threadPool
                        .submit((Callable<List<ThumbCreatorInfo>>) thumbConsumerImpl);
            }
            msg = (TextMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(destination);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            _log4j.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            _log4j.error("Please check the queue server!JMSException!", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log4j.error("", e);
        }
    } while (countFlag < 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do. If you're trying to have multiple messages processed concurrently, get away from the JmsTemplate and use a [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) with [concurrentConsumers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers%28int%29). Also available via the [JMS namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace).

For example, it seems that you could throw away all the code that you're showing in your question and use this instead:

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="10">
    <jms:listener destination="some.queue" ref="fooService" method="handleNewFoo"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

That will automatically spawn up to 10 threads for concurrent message processing. When a message comes in, it will use one of the worker threads to call fooService.handleNewFoo(), where fooService is a bean in your Spring context.

**Edit:** I've created a sample project on github showing a basic Spring JMS setup. You can browse the source at https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/basic-spring-jms or just clone and run it:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=rds.jms.Main -pl basic-spring-jms
```

There's a main class that starts a JMS broker and starts Spring. When Spring starts, it inits a bean that begins sending JMS messages. There's also a Spring message listener as I described above that consumes messages and passes them to the same bean that produces messages, which prints them to stdout.

Comment: My consumers just let one thread dispatches.Then let subThreads do process.

Comment: @user808032: Right, you seem to be rewriting stuff that Spring already does. I updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: OH.So , Is there only one client connection with 10 threads ?Thanks!

Comment: By default, unless an external transaction manager is being used, yes. A single connection will be created. That connection will be used to create a single session. That session will be used to create a consumer for each of the 10 specified threads. This is [all tunable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setCacheLevel%28int%29).

Comment: Hi Ryan . I am not familiar .Can you give me a full exmaple to my Email linzuxiong1988@gmail.com?Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much~I will modify my code , consumer, in 2~4 days .Then run it in server~~~

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using an MDP?  Seems like you're recreating Spring functionality.

Example MDP:

```
public class MyMDP implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            ...do whatever...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I donot know the Spring JMS well .

Comment: How can I make sure that the many messages are given sub threads? Codes should like:  new ThumbConsumerTaskImpl(jmsTemplate,destination);   in the subthreads :(TextMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(destination); and MDP.

Comment: Your idea is so good .  And how have MDP a relationship with a jmsTemplate ?