# Spring annotation equivalent for jms:listener-container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking into JMS using Spring and wish to create a some concurrent consumers of a particular queue when my MVC webapp starts up.

I've seen the following XML config elsewhere on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861144):

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="10">
    <jms:listener destination="some.queue" ref="fooService" method="handleNewFoo"/>
</jms:listener-container>
```

I'm using Spring configuration in Java as opposed to XML. Can someone please help out with the syntax for Spring annotation?

My existing JmsConfiguration.java looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="net.domain.orders")
public class JmsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(new ActiveMQQueue("orders.queue"));
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

}
```

I have searched many examples but all I have found so far are XML-based.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html):

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    dmlc.setDestination(new ActiveMQQueue("orders.queue"));

    // To schedule our concurrent listening tasks
    dmlc.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());

    // To perform actual message processing
    dmlc.setMessageListener(messageListener());

    dmlc.setConcurrentConsumers(10);

    // ... more parameters that you might want to inject ...
    return dmlc;
}
```

Read [the JMS namespace documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) for information about mapping XML parameters to Java parameters.